# Softkeyboard not shown after return to activity by pressing HomeButton

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, soft-keyboard

I have one activity in that am displaying softkeyboard below an alert dialog, the problem is When i go back to home screen by pressing home button then again i will launch activity by long pressing Homekey button only the dialog will be visible but softkeyboard is not visible.??

I have also checked below links, but no use

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

[android: softkeyboard not shown after return to activity, layout remains panned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135323/android-softkeyboard-not-shown-after-return-to-activity-layout-remains-panned)