# When to use a Custom CursorLoader?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

In my app I want to show a list of apps that I have placed in an resource file.
I parse the XML(resource) file and then save the value in a `SQLiteDatabase`. I have implemented my Database inside a `ContentProvider`. What I want to know is do I need a **Custom CursorLoader** (should I extend `CursorLoader`?)? or will `CursorLoader` itself will be sufficient. I have seen an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842272/how-can-i-refresh-my-listfragment-when-it-returns-to-the-layout-from-back-stack), but in this no `ContentProvider` has been used.

Can someone explain when should I implement a **Custom CursorLoader** as against using the original one?
(A little unrelated) Also what would be the best practice, to implement a database with or without a `ContentProvider`?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: all you need is a custom ContentProvider, no need to extend a CursorLoader

Comment: I also want to know when to use a Custom CursorLoader and when not to use it.

Comment: to be honest i never had a need to extend CursorLoader, so i cannot help in that issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to implement it -

1. If using a `ContentProvider` there is no need to extend the `CursorLoader`.
2. If not using a `ContentProvider` and using a `SQLiteDatabase` instead, we can extend the `CursorLoader` with our Custom-Loader and override the `loadInBackground()` method of `CursorLoader` and instead of querying the `ContentProvider` we can query the `SQLiteDatabase`.
3. While using a `SQLiteDatabase` we can extend `AsyncTaskLoader`, however, this is more 
   tedious method than one specified in **2**.